# How to move li items up or down after a corresponding button is clicked in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is the problem I am working on

A website needs a list where users can rank their favorite foods. Write the setup function, which should register click handlers on all Up! and Down! buttons. The Up! button should move the list item one place up in the list, while Down! button should move the list item one place down in the list.

For example, consider this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = `<ol>
  <li><button>Up!</button>Taco<button>Down!</button></li>
  <li><button>Up!</button>Pizza<button>Down!</button></li>
  <li><button>Up!</button>Eggs<button>Down!</button></li>
</ol>`;

setup();
```

If the button Up! button in Pizza list item is clicked, Pizza should be the first item in the list, while Taco should be the second item.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
function setup() {
  $.fn.moveUp = function() {
    before = $(this).prev();
    $(this).insertBefore(before)
  }

  $.fn.moveDown = function() {
    after=$(this).next();
    $(this).insertAfter(after)
  }

  $('li').find("button:contains('Up!')").click(function() {
    $(this).moveUp()
  })

  $('li').find("button:contains('Down!')").click(function() {
    $(this).moveDown()
  })
}
```

I thought the creation of moveUp() and moveDown() would get the job done but I'm missing something here

Comment: `this`, inside the click handlers, are the buttons.  Not the `li` elements

Comment: You could keep most your logic by changing the click event handlers to do `$(this).closest('li')` before your method call

Comment: Nice, so needed to do $(this).parent.moveUp() etc. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/xhfo3qty/

Looks like you're manipulating the wrong element. Try giving your buttons classes for better performance out of your listener, and using the .parent() method inside the callback. I've given the buttons classes, because as a preference I'm not a fan of using find. I prefer to use direct selectors, but this is not necessary.

```
<ol>
  <li><button class="up">Up!</button>Taco<button class="down">Down!</button> </li>
  <li><button class="up">Up!</button>Pizza<button class="down">Down!</button></li>
  <li><button class="up">Up!</button>Eggs<button class="down">Down!</button></li>
</ol>


$.fn.moveUp = function() {
  before = $(this).prev();
  $(this).insertBefore(before)
}

$.fn.moveDown = function() {
  after=$(this).next();
  $(this).insertAfter(after)
}

$('.up').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().moveUp()
})

$('.down').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().moveDown()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [wrxsti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791475/10871073), you can replace the up and down selectors like so without needing to modify the HTML:

```
$("button:contains('Up!')").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().moveUp()
})

$("button:contains('Down!')").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().moveDown()
})
```